# How can i make my if statement return value

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

Currently i am looking for a way to automaticly calculate and track my loss and winnings in a formular.
I have made the following sheets document: [Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/520ck.png)

Currently i am trying to make an `IF` that returns the value of a win or loss. The if should do so that if my Coum I4 is equal to Win i should return `(D4*E4)+J4` and if it's not equal to win, it should return `J4-D4`

I've tried using the following if statement in my document, but it just returns `#ERROR!`: `=IF(I4 = "Win",((D4*E4)+J4) , J4-D4)`
Any that can see what i am doing wrong, since it return error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try:

```
=IF(I4 ="Win"; (D4*E4)+J4; J4-D4)
```

### update

or use arrayformula in row 4:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(I4 ="Win"; (D4:D*E4:E)+J4:J; J4:J-D4:D))
```

Comment: @Ganggang answer updated, dont drag it. use arrayformula

Comment: Actually found the answere myself, it was because i edited it alittle, and used gee value of j5, with the value of j5. So edited it to minus the value of j4 with j5 :) THanks againn, was a huge help.